# Mongoose, sub document is objects and not json

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am querying my mongodb using mongoose, but i don't understand why the returned sub docs are just of type Object, instead of JSON.

Using

```
  hero.find({} ,{'deck' : {$elemMatch:{name:'Guard Tower'}}}, function(err, tower) {
    console.log(tower);
  }
```

returns

```
[ { _id: 507ac406ba6ecb1316000001,
    deck: 
     [ { name: 'Guard Tower',
         description: 'This tower shoots stuff.',
         cost: 13,
         sellValue: 7,
         radius: 180,
         speed: 40,
         dmg_min: 0,
         dmg_max: 0,
         actual_height: 40,
         sprite: 'guardtower_red.png',
         anim: [Object],
         size: [Object],
         projectile: [Object],
         upgrade: [Object] } ] } ]
```

Subdocument like anim, size, projectile, upgrade, is Object, i need the information nested, how can i get the information? Without making another query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The all docs and subdocs are objects in JavaScript.  It's just that `console.log` uses the default depth of 2 when calling `util.inspect` to format your document for output.  You can output all levels of the document by calling [`util.inspect`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors) yourself:

```
var util = require('util');

hero.find({} ,{'deck' : {$elemMatch:{name:'Guard Tower'}}}, function(err, tower) {
    console.log(util.inspect(tower, false, null)); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the query on Mongoose using find() as you did will return Mongoose Documents (not JSON). You can use the lean() method to return POJOs:

```
hero
 .find({} ,{'deck' : {$elemMatch:{name:'Guard Tower'}}})
 .lean()
 .exec(function(err, tower) {
   //tower is a JSON here
   console.log(tower);
 });
```

But what JohnnyHK said it's true about the console log, it will only show nested documents as [Object].

UPDATE: Beware that using .lean() will return objects and any virtual fields or special getters you might have will be ignored.

Comment: Using [`lean`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) will return POJOs not JSON. Also if you had any virtual fields or special getter functions they will not be applied and thus not present in the POJO. An alternative assuming the schema has `getters: true` would be to use the [`toJSON`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON) method for mongoose documents as so: `console.log(tower.toJSON())`

Comment: Yes. That's true Jason. Any virtual fields or getters will be missed.

Answer (score 0):

JohnnyHK is correct however a simpler approach if you just want to log out JSON would be

```
console.log(tower.toJSON());
```

You can see my comment to Rodrigo about why this works.