# how to use $group in mongodb/mongoose aggregation in grouping the subdocuments?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This corresponds to my question on [how to use mapreduce in mongoose/mongodb query subdocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919149/how-to-use-mapreduce-in-mongoose-mongodb-query-subdocument), in that question, I used the map reduce to query the subdocument.

Now I tried the solution of aggregation to query all the messages sent from 'user1'

```
model.aggregate(
    { $match: {user:'username'} },  // query the document
    { $unwind: "$msgs" },   // break the 'msgs' array into subdocuments
    { $match: { "msgs.s" : 'user1'} }, // match the filed in subdocuments
    { $project: { _id: 0, 'msgs.d':1,'msgs.m':1,'msgs.r':1 }}, // project the fileds 
    { $group : { _id : "$_id", msgs : { $addToSet : "$msgs" } }}, // don't know how to group the data
    { $sort: {"msgs.d " : -1} },
    function (err, data ) { 
        if(err) callback(err);
        else callback(null,data);
})
```

the results I got is

```
[ { msgs:
     { m: 'I want to meet you',
       d: Sat Jan 04 2014 08:52:54 GMT+0000 (GMT),
       r: false } },
  { msgs:
     { m: 'I want to meet you',
       d: Sat Jan 04 2014 08:53:02 GMT+0000 (GMT),
       r: false } },
  { msgs:
     { m: 'I want to meet youd',
       d: Sat Jan 04 2014 08:53:06 GMT+0000 (GMT),
       r: false } },
]
```

it is right results, but still not in good format, I think I don't know how to use the $group to group the subdocument into a flatten array.

The result I want is

```
{'msgs':[ 
     { m: 'I want to meet you',
       d: Sat Jan 04 2014 08:52:54 GMT+0000 (GMT),
       r: false },

     { m: 'I want to meet you',
       d: Sat Jan 04 2014 08:53:02 GMT+0000 (GMT),
       r: false },

     { m: 'I want to meet youd',
       d: Sat Jan 04 2014 08:53:06 GMT+0000 (GMT),
       r: false },
]}
```

how to use the $group in aggregation?

if I uncomment the $group in the query.

the result I got is like the following

```
[  
    { _id: null,
    msgs:[ 
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object]
       ] 
     } 
]
```

Thanks for  JohnnyHK 's answer, it helps me a lot in understanding the aggregate. 
Now I have two more little problems

**1.** the subdocuments I fetched is not sorted according to the time, in my code, I used `{ $sort: {"msgs.d " : -1} }` in the query to sort all the subdocuments , but failed to work

**2.** If I need to add a 'sender' field in the results accompanied with all his sent messages, how can I do it in the $group
I tried this way

```
{ $group : { sender : "$msgs.s", msgs : { $addToSet : "$msgs" } }}
```

or

```
{ $group : { sender : sender, msgs : { $addToSet : "$msgs" } }}
```

doesn't work

**3.** the current result gives me two levels of array, can I remove the first outer array, since it is not needed

Comment: If I uncomment your `$group` line to include it in the pipeline, it generates the exact format you're looking for.

Comment: Hi,  I tested on my previous $group in my code, the result is shown in the post. but this output is still not exactly what I want

Comment: The `[Object]` lines are likely just an artifact of the way you're calling `console.log`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886222/mongoose-sub-document-is-objects-and-not-json/12886405#12886405

Comment: Oh, thanks, it works well, now I see the result output structure. But there are two level of arrays, can I remove the outer array since it is not needed at all